# Pass instance of derived to base in order to call derived method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to implement pop() in the base class, and have pop() call the proper derived class heapifyUp() method from the derived class. I realize that I can make a pop() for each derived, but I'm interested in how one should solve this.

How can I make a "generic" way to pass either minHeap or maxHeap instances to pop()?

```
class Heap
{
    public :

    int size;
    int *items;
    Heap(int n) { this->items = new int[n]; this->size = 0; }
    ~Heap() { delete[] items; }
    int peek() { return items[0]; }

    int _pop()
    {
        int top = items[0];
        items[0] = items[size - 1];
        --size;
        heapifyDown();
        return top;
    }
}

class minHeap : Heap
{
    public :

    minHeap(int capacity) : Heap(capacity) {}

    void heapifyUp()
    {
        int index = size - 1;
        while(hasParent(index) && (parent(index) > items[index]))
        {
            swap(getParentIndex(index), index);
            index = getParentIndex(index);
        }
    }

    void heapifyDown()
    {

    }
}

class maxHeap : Heap
{
public:
    maxHeap(int capacity) : Heap(capacity) {}
    ~maxHeap() {}

    void heapifyUp()
    {

    }

    void heapifyDown()
    {

    }

};
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you need just to declare `class Heap { virtual void heapifyUp() = {}; // ...etc...`, and, of course, re-read the section on "virtual functions" in your text book.

Comment: You can make `Heap` a template class that accepts a `HeapStrategy` template parameter. The `HeapStrategy` would then be either `MinHeapStrategy` or `MaxHeapStrategy`. Then `using MinHeap = Heap<MinHeapStrategy>` and `using MaxHeap = Heap<MaxHeapStrategy>`. This is a generic programming technique called _Policy-Based Design_. Sorry, I don't have time to elaborate this into a more complete answer.

Comment: Oops, I should have written `virtual void heapifyUp() = 0;` above - looks like I need to re-read that section too!

Comment: @EmileCormier - Thank you! I will read more about this tonight during my study session.

Comment: @KenY-N - haha....bitten by the old textbook. You're right, Ken. I haven't seen this since 4 years ago when I had a single C++ as an engineering student. Perhaps I should dig out Mr. Gaddis's book. But sometimes one needs to know the actual words to use before they can begin looking for help. No?

Answer (score 2):

> I  want to implement `pop()` in the base class, and have `pop()` call the proper derived class `heapifyUp()` method from the derived class.

That's a sign of poor design. The names `heapifyUp` and `heapifyDown` imply/assume  a strategy.

You can stick with the poor design and create

```
virtual heapifyUp() = 0;
virtual heapifyDown() = 0;
```

in the base class and implement them in the derived class.

Another option is to use a `virtual` helper function that can be overridden in the derived classes to do their own special things while taking advantage of the commonality of the base class.

```
class Heap
{
    public :

    ...

    int _pop()
    {
       return _pop_impl();
    }

    private:

    virtual int _pop_impl()
    {
        int top = items[0];
        items[0] = items[size - 1];
        --size;
        return top;
    }
}

class minHeap : Heap
{
   ...

   virtual int _pop_impl()
   {
      // Additional code for this class.
      // ...

      int ret = Heap::_pop_impl();

      // Additional code for this class.
      // ...
      return ret;
   }
}

class maxHeap : Heap
{
   ...

   virtual int _pop_impl()
   {
      // Additional code for this class.
      // ...

      int ret = Heap::_pop_impl();

      // Additional code for this class.
      // ...
      return ret;
   }
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu - Thank you for taking the time to explain w.r.t.design principles. 

So what if Heap can only be called by Max or MinHeap? Is it still a poor choice? I had a reason for only wanting to define pop() once. 

What about using a template instead, which would allow me to keep my intent with not duplicating code? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @AspiringCodeMonkey, you raise important questions. Unfortunately, a comment is the right place to answer them. Also, the kinds of questions that you ask are better asked at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.